# Excel VBA macro - using cell value in formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a repetitive task that I am trying to solve with a macro.

I have a cell with a number - let's say cell N4 holds `5782.3`.

Now I would like to change the B4 cell content to `=IF($K4<>0,5728.3,0)`

How do i do it?
I have tried the following:

```
 Dim a As Double
 a = ActiveCell.Value
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC4<>0,a,0)"
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

But then I get in the cell `IF($K4<>0,a,0)` How should I write it?

Comment: something like this: `Range("B4").Formula = "=IF($K4<>0," & Range("K4").Value & ",0)"`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use VBA for this.

If your variable *a* is the number in *N4*, you could just use the cell formula:

```
=IF($K4<>0,$N4,0)
```

The reason your VBA isn't working as expected is because *a* is inside quotes, and is treated as the character "a". Use:

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC4<>0," & a & ",0)"
```